# I'm new at integer

Tags: int

I'm new at java and I have a problem.

```
   int a = 4;
   int b = 8;
   int c = a + b;

   System.out.println("Number: " + c + b);
```

When I write this, console says:

Number:128

Why not number is 16?

Answer (score 0):

Because `"Number: "` is a string, so the plus signs are appending the integers to the end of the string.

What you want is something like `System.out.println("Number: " + (c + b));`

The extra parenthesis tell Java to compute the numerical addition first before adding it to the string.

Answer (score 0):

The result is

```
"Number:" "12" "8"
```

Variables `c` is `12` and `b` is `8`.
At first `c` converted to string and appended and after that `b` is converted to string and appended.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is left-associative - you start with the String `"Number: "`, then calculate `+ c`, which would just convert `c` to a String and append it (resulting in `"Number: 12"`), and then the same with `b`, appending another `"8"`, resulting in `"Number: 128"`.

If you want to evaluate `c+b` first, as `int`s, you should surround that calculation with parenthesis:

```
System.out.println("Number: " + (c + b));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is doing string concatenation instead of arithmetic calculation. So the value of c 12 and the value of b 8 are printed right next to each other.